# boolean statement on excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, boolean-logic

I have three columns where as if one column falls below 79 it should show as a Y. Looking on the picture there are blank columns, blank columns doesn't really have a score, what would be the formula for this?

[image]

Comment: `=IF({cell}="","",{formula})` - replace those `{...}` with you references and formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Try following formula.

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1>1,A1<79),AND(B1>1,B1<79),AND(C1>1,C1<79)),"Y","N")
```

[image]